# How to find and plot the local maxima of a polynomial regression curve in R?

Tags: r, plot, regression

I have yield data for a farm (independent variable) and various nutrients which serve as predictors. I have performed univariate (cubic) linear regression using `lm(y ~ ploy(x,3))`. Then I plotted the predictor variable (P) against the yield, and added a best fit curve (Figure 1). How do I then find the local maxima of this curve, and add a point to my plot which includes the value of this fitted yield (Figure 2)? I have looked into the `findPeaks()` function from the [quantmod package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantmod/versions/0.4-12/topics/findPeaks), but have not been able to implement.

Figure 1 - Plot I have created:
[image]

Figure 2 - Plot I would like to create:
[image]

My code:

```
head(farm)
P <- farm$P
Yield <- farm$Yield
fit <- lm(Yield ~ poly(P,3), data=farm)
plot(P, Yield, col="lightblue", xlab = "P", ylab = "Yield", main="Farm - polynomial fit")
lines(sort(P), fitted(fit)[order(P)], col='darkred', type='l', cex=10)
```

My data:

```
farm <- structure(list(Yield = c(28.3818, 27.0422555556, 31.5444454545, 
32.2084818182, 25.983, 43.49634, 53.3981333333, 59.19274, 61.23185, 
63.83512, 64.5388, 63.08576, 63.83954, 62.7838333333, 64.10366, 
67.5600666667, 67.6325, 68.0023, 63.02148, 64.0025666667, 64.19196, 
60.4893, 65.2803333333, 62.28096, 59.1914, 59.37304, 58.6482333333, 
58.08474, 58.98306, 61.52755, 61.9972, 62.0188833333, 61.09072, 
58.44715, 61.06646, 59.6103833333, 60.57035, 67.5646, 67.85488, 
71.5719571429, 50.30092, 22.80535, 62.26542, 62.0754333333, 58.46464, 
62.7326833333, 65.53482, 63.3064666667, 63.68004, 63.5212166667, 
64.65068, 66.19655, 66.0726, 66.6404666667, 65.02208, 62.1035666667, 
61.78824, 61.0844166667, 60.1723, 61.6899333333, 57.8784166667, 
56.8886666667, 59.13944, 57.26695, 69.5792666667, 61.9865166667, 
55.7342, 53.7012857143, 56.9748166667, 56.8706333333, 61.3384166667, 
52.87725, 29.2331888889, 15.5046, 42.943, 44.590325, 50.09525, 
52.68065, 53.0983714286, 19.43875, 38.06708, 59.9217666667, 62.0287166667, 
66.59496, 64.3986333333, 64.4089333333, 64.6951, 63.8205, 63.6122, 
62.51384, 63.2565666667, 62.47745, 61.42234, 62.6233166667, 62.0730333333, 
60.81996, 60.6490833333, 58.4331333333, 59.94638, 61.4119333333
), P = c(90L, 93L, 97L, 97L, 100L, 106L, 107L, 114L, 118L, 120L, 
121L, 121L, 120L, 120L, 121L, 115L, 116L, 113L, 101L, 90L, 85L, 
84L, 85L, 85L, 83L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 84L, 87L, 
87L, 88L, 88L, 92L, 93L, 95L, 80L, 67L, 85L, 90L, 88L, 90L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 88L, 78L, 73L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 
69L, 69L, 69L, 71L, 75L, 71L, 71L, 78L, 82L, 84L, 84L, 77L, 64L, 
51L, 99L, 104L, 107L, 109L, 107L, 99L, 102L, 115L, 120L, 121L, 
121L, 120L, 121L, 112L, 111L, 101L, 101L, 89L, 89L, 85L, 84L, 
83L, 83L, 82L, 83L, 83L), Mg = c(666L, 667L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 
670L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 672L, 673L, 673L, 673L, 673L, 673L, 645L, 
645L, 636L, 594L, 553L, 535L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 
534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 543L, 540L, 570L, 568L, 576L, 576L, 577L, 
577L, 577L, 574L, 572L, 575L, 576L, 576L, 576L, 577L, 577L, 577L, 
577L, 577L, 577L, 574L, 567L, 565L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 
564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 565L, 564L, 553L, 519L, 509L, 509L, 509L, 
508L, 505L, 502L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 670L, 670L, 668L, 669L, 672L, 
672L, 673L, 673L, 673L, 673L, 636L, 636L, 594L, 594L, 553L, 553L, 
534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 534L), S = c(29L, 30L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 34L, 31L, 
35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 38L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 33L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 31L, 32L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L), K = c(537L, 542L, 549L, 549L, 
554L, 563L, 565L, 576L, 584L, 586L, 589L, 588L, 587L, 587L, 588L, 
565L, 566L, 557L, 516L, 477L, 460L, 459L, 460L, 459L, 456L, 455L, 
455L, 454L, 455L, 457L, 458L, 463L, 461L, 478L, 476L, 482L, 482L, 
489L, 491L, 493L, 470L, 447L, 477L, 485L, 482L, 485L, 487L, 486L, 
487L, 487L, 487L, 488L, 495L, 512L, 517L, 514L, 513L, 513L, 512L, 
512L, 510L, 509L, 509L, 513L, 519L, 513L, 495L, 454L, 443L, 446L, 
446L, 435L, 414L, 392L, 552L, 561L, 565L, 569L, 565L, 551L, 557L, 
579L, 586L, 589L, 589L, 587L, 589L, 555L, 554L, 515L, 516L, 476L, 
475L, 459L, 458L, 457L, 456L, 455L, 456L, 457L), Ca = c(4795L, 
4796L, 4797L, 4797L, 4797L, 4799L, 4799L, 4800L, 4801L, 4801L, 
4802L, 4802L, 4802L, 4802L, 4802L, 4779L, 4779L, 4771L, 4736L, 
4701L, 4686L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 
4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4789L, 4754L, 5135L, 5100L, 5204L, 5204L, 
5205L, 5205L, 5205L, 5202L, 5200L, 5203L, 5204L, 5204L, 5204L, 
5205L, 5205L, 5205L, 5205L, 5205L, 5205L, 5125L, 4886L, 4807L, 
4806L, 4806L, 4806L, 4806L, 4806L, 4806L, 4806L, 4806L, 4806L, 
4807L, 4806L, 4687L, 4329L, 4211L, 4211L, 4211L, 4210L, 4207L, 
4204L, 4797L, 4798L, 4799L, 4799L, 4799L, 4797L, 4798L, 4801L, 
4801L, 4802L, 4802L, 4802L, 4802L, 4771L, 4771L, 4736L, 4736L, 
4701L, 4701L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L, 4685L
)), .Names = c("Yield", "P", "Mg", "S", "K", "Ca"), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There is a function to find peaks here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/how-to-find-local-peaks-valleys-in-a-series-of-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients of `fit` give you an explicit polynomial equation for the regression line. You can therefore find the maximum (or maxima in cases where there's more than one) analytically by taking the first and second derivatives of this polynomial:

```
fit <- lm(Yield ~ poly(P,3, raw=TRUE), data=farm)  # Note use of raw=TRUE, otherwise poly returns orthogonal polynomials

# Plot data points
with(farm, plot(P, Yield, col="lightblue", ylim=c(0, max(Yield)), 
                xlab = "P", ylab = "Yield", main="Farm - polynomial fit"))

# Add model fit
P = seq(min(farm$P), max(farm$P), length=1000)
pred = data.frame(P,
                  Yield=predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(P)))

with(pred, lines(P, Yield, col='darkred', type='l', cex=10))

# Vector of model coefficients
cf = coef(fit)

# First derivative of fit. This is just for Illustration; we won't plot this
#  equation directly, but we'll find its roots to get the locations of 
#  local maxima and minima.
D1 = cf[2] + 2*cf[3]*pred$P + 3*cf[4]*pred$P^2

# Roots of first derivative (these are locations where first derivative = 0).
#  Use quadratic formula to find roots.
D1roots = (-2*cf[3] + c(-1,1)*sqrt((2*cf[3])^2 - 4*3*cf[4]*cf[2]))/(2*3*cf[4])

# Second derivative at the two roots. 
D2atD1roots =  2*cf[3] + 6*cf[4]*D1roots

# Local maxima are where the second derivative is negative
max_x = D1roots[which(D2atD1roots < 0)]
max_y = cf %*% max_x^(0:3)

# Plot local maxima
points(max_x, max_y, pch=16, col="red")

# Add values of Yield at local maxima
text(max_x, max_y, label=round(max_y,2), adj=c(0.5,-1), cex=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Incredible! Thank you!

Comment: This is so helpful. I am wondering how one could extend this to 4th or 6th polynomials? or do you always want the first and second derivatives regardless?

Comment: This is true for any (smooth*) function. The first derivative is zero at the extrema (maxima and minima) and the second derivative tells you whether a given extremum is a maximum or a minimum. *Technical point: "smooth" meaning that the first and second derivatives exist at a given point (which is true for all polynomials and for many other common functions, but isn't necessarily always true).

Comment: In case these ideas are new to you, they come from differential calculus. If you Google `finding maxima and minima` or `second derivative test` you'll find lots of resources on these topics.

Answer (score 0):

as you don't give a minimal reproducible example it is a bit hard to give a code. But an advice would be to look for the first closest to zero points of the derivative of your fit curve. You can simply calculate the derivative

```
curve <- fitted(fit)[order(P)]
derivative <- diff(curve)/(diff(order(P)))
```

and then look for the zeros of your function. Here an approch could be to find the min values of `abs(derivative)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I did provide a csv file and my regression code in the question - is there more that I could do to make the question minimally reproducible? Thanks again.

Comment: Typically it is considered "bad etiquette" to provide links to external data. Instead, use `dput()` to have R generate an easily copy-pastable representation of your data and include it with your code. If the whole data set is too large, pick out a suitable subset and base your example around that.

Comment: @JasonMatney I didn't see the link to the data. I ll give it a try. Yes jdobres is right, it is better to have an esay copy paste example. Like you could simply give a minimal vector giving your fit and ordered P, and ask for the way of finding the local maxima.

Comment: @denis Ah great to know - thanks! I'll make a copy/paste example and start doing this in the future.